# Update data based on date comparison and picking the latest/earliest date data to the main table

Tags: oracle

I have two tables, Job_Events and Comp_Events, as follows :

```
Job_events

userid eventstartdt         jobcode
    10 2014-08-18 00:00:00  j1
    10 2015-07-27 00:00:00  j1
    10 2015-03-23 00:00:00  j2
    10 2015-12-28 00:00:00  j3 
    10 2015-03-23 00:00:00  j4
    10 2015-03-23 00:00:00  j5 

Comp_Events

userid eventstartdt        salary
    10 2014-08-11 00:00:00   1000
    10 2015-03-23 00:00:00   1525
    10 2015-06-21 00:00:00    500
    10 2016-03-21 00:00:00   2000
```

expected output:

```
jobcompevents

userid jobeventstartdt      jobcode salary
    10 2014-08-18 00:00:00  j1        1000
    10 2015-07-27 00:00:00  j1         500
    10 2015-03-23 00:00:00  j2        1525
    10 2015-12-28 00:00:00  j3         500
    10 2015-03-23 00:00:00  j4        1525
    10 2015-03-23 00:00:00  j5        1525
```

PS: I cannot join based on YYYYMM format, because month based data may not be available. I should pick the latest/earliest compevents for that job record so that it is merged with one record.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I created more input data for additional testing. The query should be able to separate inputs (and outputs) by `userid`, and it should show `NULL` for `salary` for a job with a start date that is before all start dates for that `userid` in the `Comp_events` table.

Please note, I edited your post to correct a very large number of typos; if this came directly from your actual setup, you will have to correct them there.

```
with
     job_events ( userid, eventstartdt, jobcode ) as (
       select 10, date '2014-08-18', 'j1' from dual union all
       select 10, date '2015-07-27', 'j1' from dual union all
       select 10, date '2015-03-23', 'j2' from dual union all
       select 10, date '2015-12-28', 'j3' from dual union all
       select 10, date '2015-03-23', 'j4' from dual union all
       select 10, date '2015-03-23', 'j5' from dual union all
       select 35, date '2014-04-18', 'j1' from dual union all
       select 35, date '2015-09-22', 'j1' from dual union all
       select 35, date '2015-10-29', 'j8' from dual
     ),
     comp_events ( userid, eventstartdt, salary ) as (
       select 10, date '2014-08-11', 1000 from dual union all
       select 10, date '2015-03-23', 1525 from dual union all
       select 10, date '2015-06-21',  500 from dual union all
       select 10, date '2016-03-21', 2000 from dual union all
       select 35, date '2015-06-15', 2850 from dual
     ),
     u ( userid, eventstartdt, jobcode, salary ) as (
       select userid, eventstartdt, jobcode, null    from   job_events
       union all
       select userid, eventstartdt, null   , salary  from   comp_events
     ),
     prep ( userid, eventstartdt, jobcode, salary ) as (
       select userid, eventstartdt, jobcode, 
              last_value(salary ignore nulls) over 
                          (partition by userid order by eventstartdt)
       from   u
     )
select   userid, eventstartdt, jobcode, salary
from     prep
where    jobcode is not null
order by userid, jobcode, eventstartdt
;
```

**Output**:

```
    USERID EVENTSTARTDT JOBCODE     SALARY
---------- ------------ ------- ----------
        10 2014-08-18   j1            1000
        10 2015-07-27   j1             500
        10 2015-03-23   j2            1525
        10 2015-12-28   j3             500
        10 2015-03-23   j4            1525
        10 2015-03-23   j5            1525
        35 2014-04-18   j1
        35 2015-09-22   j1            2850
        35 2015-10-29   j8            2850

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you so much,